# Getting different results when dereferencing a pointer to an integer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dereference

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int* a){
    int b=*a++;
    cout<<b<<endl;
}
void fun1(int *a){
    int b=*a+1;
    cout<<b<<endl;
}
int main(){
    int n=5;
    fun(&n);//output remains 5
    fun1(&n);//output incremented by 1
}
```

In the function fun the value of n does not get incremented when done as shown in the above code, on the other hand in function fun1 the value of n gets incremented by 1.What is the problem with the first approach to increment n?

Comment: @walnut yeah thanks a lot ..your mentioned post cleared my doubt.

Comment: @Maestro that won't do. You need preincrement `int b = ++*a;`

Comment: @Maestro, int b=(*a)++ translates to use the value at which the pointer is pointing and then increment it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you observe is expected by [the operator precendence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

In the first case it is `a++`, the previous value of `a` dereferenced.

In the second: the value of `a` dereferenced plus 1.